# "Authenticated No" after programmatically login in custom-entity user in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

Programmatically logging in the user through:

```
$user = new CustomEntityUser();
$user->setUsername("foo");
$user->setPassword("bar");

$entityManager->persist($user);
$entityManager->flush();

$token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, $user->getPassword(), "main", $user->getRoles());
$this->get('security.token_storage')->setToken($token);
```

doesn't authenticate the user properly. The debug bar goes yellow and says: "Authenticated No". The name of the firewall is `main`.

The user-entity-class has implemented the `Serializeable`-interface according to documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to have the user-entity-class implement the `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\EquatableInterface`, such as e.g.:

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function isEqualTo(UserInterface $user)
{
    if (! $user instanceof User) {
        return false;
    }

    if ($this->username !== $user->getUsername()) {
        return false;
    }

    if ($this->password !== $user->getPassword()) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

After doing this, the user is successfully authenticated.

If above fix doesn't work, ensure that the data is properly validated. E.g:

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", length=40, unique=true)
 */
private $username;
```

and then generating a username with more than 40 characters will still give the same problem.